# Why is _mm512_store_pd super slow in this matrix multiplication code?

Tags: c, performance, gcc, matrix, avx512

I'm playing with avx512 and matrix multiplications but I must be doing something wrong because I have awful performances when I try to store my results using _mm512_store_pd.

Here are the relevant snippets of code, first the data structure I'm using and how I initialize it:

```
typedef struct {
        double* values;
        int nb_l;
        int nb_c;
} matrix;

matrix* alloc_matrix(int nb_l, int nb_c){
        matrix* tmp_matrix = (matrix*)malloc(sizeof(matrix));
        tmp_matrix->values = (double*)aligned_alloc(64, sizeof(double) * nb_l * nb_c);
        tmp_matrix->nb_l = nb_l;
        tmp_matrix->nb_c = nb_c;
        return tmp_matrix;
}
```

And here is how I'm trying to multiply two matrices initialized elsewhere in my code:

```
matrix* mult_matrix(matrix* A, matrix* B){
        /* avx512 */
        matrix* res_matrix = zero_matrix(A->nb_l, B->nb_c);
        double* res_ptr; // start index of the current line in res_matrix
        double* B_ptr; // start index of the current line in B

        __m512d A_broadcast, B_l_8, res_ptr_8;
        for (unsigned int idx_A = 0; idx_A < A->nb_l * A-> nb_c; idx_A++){
                // broadcast current value of A  eight times
                A_broadcast = _mm512_set1_pd(A->values[idx_A]);
                res_ptr = res_matrix->values + (idx_A / A->nb_c) * B->nb_c;
                B_ptr = B->values + (idx_A % A->nb_c) * B->nb_c;
                for (unsigned int offset_B = 0; offset_B < B->nb_c; offset_B+=8){
                        B_l_8 = _mm512_load_pd(&B_ptr[offset_B]);
                        res_ptr_8 = _mm512_load_pd(&res_ptr[offset_B]);
                        _mm512_store_pd(
                                &res_ptr[offset_B] , 
                                _mm512_fmadd_pd(A_broadcast, B_l_8, res_ptr_8)
                                );
                }
        }
        return res_matrix;
```

The results are OK but _mm512_store_pd takes ~90% of the execution time, actually this avx512 code is barely faster than its non avx version.

I've tried everything I could think of but I'm can't find why I have such disappointing performances with this code. Do you have any idea ?

Thanks.

***EDIT 1***

Here is the non avx code

```
        matrix* res_matrix = zero_matrix(A->nb_l, B->nb_c);
        double* res_ptr; // start index of the current line in res_matrix
        double* B_ptr; // start index of the current line in B

        for (unsigned int idx_A = 0; idx_A < A->nb_l * A-> nb_c; idx_A++){
                res_ptr = res_matrix->values + (idx_A / A->nb_c) * B->nb_c; 
                B_ptr = B->values + (idx_A % A->nb_c) * B->nb_c; 
                for (unsigned int offset_B = 0; offset_B < B->nb_c; offset_B++){                    
                        res_ptr[offset_B] += A->values[idx_A] * B_ptr[offset_B];
                }
        }
        return res_matrix;
```

All matrices are 512x512 random matrices, each multiplication is repeated 50 times and the running time is averaged.

Finally the snippet below should be OK in order to test avx and non_avx versions of my code. I've compiled it with gcc 8.3.0 using the following options: gcc -Ofast -mavx -mavx512f -m64 -mfpmath=sse -mfma -flto -funroll-loops matrix_minimal.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

typedef struct {
        double* values;
        int nb_l;
        int nb_c;
} matrix;

matrix* alloc_matrix(int nb_l, int nb_c){
        matrix* tmp_matrix = (matrix*)malloc(sizeof(matrix));
        tmp_matrix->values = (double*)aligned_alloc(64, sizeof(double) * nb_l * nb_c);
        tmp_matrix->nb_l = nb_l;
        tmp_matrix->nb_c = nb_c;
        return tmp_matrix;
}

void free_matrix(matrix** to_free){
        free((*to_free)->values);
        free(*to_free);
}

matrix* zero_matrix(int nb_l, int nb_c){
        matrix* z_matrix;
        z_matrix = alloc_matrix(nb_l, nb_c);
        for (int idx=0; idx < nb_l * nb_c; idx++){
                z_matrix->values[idx] = 0.0;
        }
        return z_matrix;
}
matrix* rand_matrix(int nb_l, int nb_c, double max_abs_val){
        static struct timeval seed; //static variables are zeroed at initialization
        matrix* rnd_matrix;
        rnd_matrix = alloc_matrix(nb_l, nb_c);

        if (seed.tv_sec == 0){ //ts_sec will never be zero after gettimeofday, whereas tv_usec could
                gettimeofday(&seed, NULL);
                srand((unsigned) seed.tv_usec);
        }
        for (int idx=0; idx < nb_l * nb_c; idx++){
                rnd_matrix->values[idx] = max_abs_val * ((double)rand() / RAND_MAX * 2.0 - 1.0);
        }

        return rnd_matrix;
}

matrix* mult_matrix_avx(matrix* A, matrix* B){
        /* pas trop mal en avx512 */
        matrix* res_matrix = zero_matrix(A->nb_l, B->nb_c);
        double* res_ptr; // start index of the current line in res_matrix
        double* B_ptr; // start index of the current line in B

        __m512d A_broadcast, B_l_8, res_ptr_8;
        for (unsigned int idx_A = 0; idx_A < A->nb_l * A-> nb_c; idx_A++){
                A_broadcast = _mm512_set1_pd(A->values[idx_A]); // broadcast current value of A eight times
                res_ptr = res_matrix->values + (idx_A / A->nb_c) * B->nb_c;
                B_ptr = B->values + (idx_A % A->nb_c) * B->nb_c;
                for (unsigned int offset_B = 0; offset_B < B->nb_c; offset_B+=8){
                        B_l_8 = _mm512_load_pd(&B_ptr[offset_B]);
                        res_ptr_8 = _mm512_load_pd(&res_ptr[offset_B]);
                        _mm512_store_pd(&res_ptr[offset_B] , _mm512_fmadd_pd(A_broadcast, B_l_8, res_ptr_8));
                }
        }
        return res_matrix;
}

matrix* mult_matrix(matrix* A, matrix* B){
        /* non avx512 */
        matrix* res_matrix = zero_matrix(A->nb_l, B->nb_c);
        double* res_ptr; // start index of the current line in res_matrix
        double* B_ptr; // start index of the current line in B

        for (unsigned int idx_A = 0; idx_A < A->nb_l * A-> nb_c; idx_A++){
                res_ptr = res_matrix->values + (idx_A / A->nb_c) * B->nb_c;
                B_ptr = B->values + (idx_A % A->nb_c) * B->nb_c;
                for (unsigned int offset_B = 0; offset_B < B->nb_c; offset_B++){
                        res_ptr[offset_B] += A->values[idx_A] * B_ptr[offset_B];
                }
        }
        return res_matrix;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        struct timeval before;
        struct timeval after;

        matrix* A = rand_matrix(512, 512, 5);
        matrix* B = rand_matrix(512, 512, 5);
        matrix *C;
        gettimeofday(&before, NULL);
        for (int j=0; j<50;j++){
                C = mult_matrix_avx(A, B);
                free_matrix(&C); // we will measure the same overhead here and in the non avx version
        }
        gettimeofday(&after, NULL);
        double delta = ((after.tv_sec - before.tv_sec) * 1000000 +
                (after.tv_usec - before.tv_usec))/50;
        printf("avx %lf ms\n", delta);
        gettimeofday(&before, NULL);
        for (int j=0; j<50;j++){
                C = mult_matrix(A, B);
                free_matrix(&C); 
        }
        gettimeofday(&after, NULL);
        delta = ((after.tv_sec - before.tv_sec) * 1000000 +
                (after.tv_usec - before.tv_usec))/50;
        printf("non avx %lf ms\n", delta);

        free_matrix(&A);
        free_matrix(&B);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `actually this avx512 code is barely faster than its non avx version` - Can you post the "non avx version"? Can you post how do you measure performance? What gcc version are you using and what compile options are you using? What parameters do you pass to `alloc_matrix` to allocate the matrix? Would you be able to create a full [MCVE]?

Comment: Your code is sub-optimal in many ways. Ideally, you should have just slightly more than one load per FMA operation, and much more FMAs before actually storing the result back (you need to keep more intermediate results in registers). Also, if your matrices don't fit into L1, you need to operate on sub-blocks which fit into L1.

Comment: More `const` and `restrict` wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

@chtz pointed out the obvious answer, I was updating the result way too often instead of relying on the mm512 registers.

If I compare this non avx version:

```
        matrix* res_matrix = alloc_matrix(A->nb_l, B->nb_c);
        double tmp;
        for (unsigned int res_l=0; res_l < res_matrix->nb_l; res_l++){
                for (unsigned int res_c=0; res_c < res_matrix->nb_c; res_c++){
                        tmp = 0.0;
                        for (int offset = 0; offset < A->nb_c; offset++){
                                tmp += A->values[res_l * A->nb_c + offset] *
                                        B->values[offset * A->nb_c + res_c];
                        }
                        res_matrix->values[res_l * res_matrix->nb_c + res_c] = tmp;
                }

        }
        return res_matrix;
```

With its exact AVX counterpart:

```
        matrix* res_matrix = alloc_matrix(A->nb_l, B->nb_c);
        __m512d res_ptr_8;

        for (unsigned int res_l=0; res_l < res_matrix->nb_l; res_l++){
                for (unsigned int res_c=0; res_c < res_matrix->nb_c; res_c+=8){
                        // compute values from res_matrix[res_l, res_c] to [res_l, res_c+7]
                        res_ptr_8 = _mm512_set1_pd(0.0);
                        for (unsigned int offset_A_c = 0; offset_A_c < A->nb_c; offset_A_c++){
                                // on the res_l th line of A pick values one at a time
                                // at coordinates A[res_l, offset_A_c].
                                // Broadcast this value eight times into a mm512 vector
                                // and perform a dot product with the 8 values found in
                                // B from coordinates [offset_A_c, res_c] to [offset_A_c, res_c + 7]
                                res_ptr_8 = _mm512_fmadd_pd(
                                        _mm512_set1_pd(A->values[res_l * A->nb_c + offset_A_c]),
                                        _mm512_load_pd(&B->values[offset_A_c * B->nb_c + res_c]),
                                        res_ptr_8);
                        }
                        _mm512_store_pd(&res_matrix->values[res_l*res_matrix->nb_c + res_c] , res_ptr_8);
                }
        }
```

The running time of the AVX code is ~7 times faster than the non-AVX one which is what I expected.

However if I compare this new AVX code to the non-AVX one pasted in the question the speed gain is only around 3, which is still good enough for me.

***Edit***

These speed gains are measured on small blocks in order to fit into cache, not on a 512*512 matrix as in the original post.

***Edit 2***
Thanks to Peter Cordes (see below, edit: it looks like I totally misunderstood what he said) here is an updated AVX code which is twice faster than the one above on 48x48 blocks. Surprisingly it's even faster than numpy/openblas on the same matrix.

```
        #define NB_L_STRIDE 8
        __m512d res_ptr_8[NB_L_STRIDE], B_ptr_8;
        for (unsigned int res_l=0; res_l < res_matrix->nb_l; res_l+=NB_L_STRIDE){
                for (unsigned int res_c=0; res_c < res_matrix->nb_c; res_c+=8){
                        for(unsigned int i=0; i<NB_L_STRIDE; i++)
                                res_ptr_8[i] = _mm512_setzero_pd();
                        for (unsigned int offset_A_c = 0; offset_A_c < A->nb_c; offset_A_c++){
                        // compute values from res_matrix[res_l, res_c] to [res_l, res_c+7]
                                // on the res_l th line of A pick values one at a time
                                // at coordinates A[res_l, offset_A_c].
                                // Broadcast this value eight times into a mm512 vector
                                // and perform a dot product with the 8 values found in
                                // B from coordinates [offset_A_c, res_c] to [offset_A_c, res_c + 7]
                                B_ptr_8 = _mm512_load_pd(&B->values[offset_A_c * B->nb_c + res_c]);
                                for(unsigned int i=0; i<NB_L_STRIDE; i++)
                                        res_ptr_8[i] = _mm512_fmadd_pd(
                                                _mm512_set1_pd(A->values[(res_l +i) * A->nb_c + offset_A_c]),
                                                B_ptr_8,
                                                res_ptr_8[i]);

                        }
                        for(unsigned int i=0; i<NB_L_STRIDE; i++)
                                _mm512_store_pd(
                                        &res_matrix->values[(res_l + i)*res_matrix->nb_c + res_c] ,
                                        res_ptr_8[i]);
                }
        }
```

Comment: This looks like it will bottleneck on FMA latency, not even on load throughput.  (And if your data wasn't hot in L1d cache, striding down a column is really bad.)  TL:DR: There's a lot of performance left on the table here; consider using a library like Eigen.

Comment: Thanks, actually the goal wasn't to design a state of the art GEMM, it was to check what avx512 can or can't do. I would never ever use this for production code.

Comment: Artificially bottlenecking your loop means you get a larger speedup than you would if for example L2 bandwidth was a limiting factor.  AVX512 helps most over AVX2+FMA when you have high computational intensity, far from bottlenecking on memory bandwidth.  (Which can be the case for a GEMM if you cache-block it correctly.)  Or when you're doing things that only AVX512 supports natively, e.g. packed int64 <-> FP conversions, or unsigned <-> FP conversions, or some shuffles.

Comment: I should have said that the speed gain was measured on blocks small enough to fit in cache, not on the original 512*512 matrix I was working on where no gain was measured.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense.  I was surprised your 512x512 matrix wasn't totally bottlenecked on cache misses.  If you were striding down 8 columns in parallel, you'd probably get a speedup there if it was 64-byte aligned.  Because then you'd be loading a whole cache line in parallel as one vector, and not coming back to touch that line again later.  Actually that is how you're vectorizing, I think.  Perhaps L2 adjacent-line prefetching is defeating that benefit of doing fewer wider strided accesses down columns, or you don't have your memory aligned.  Doing 2 vectors in parallel could help.

Comment: Thanks to your comment I was able to double the speed of the AVX code, I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: I meant getting a speedup on a 512x512 matrix by using all the doubles of a whole cache line as you loop down a column.  Are you sure your new version is even correct?  For a given row`*`column dot product, aren't you only getting every 8th column?  Maybe I'm misreading something but I was picturing that you'd have the `+i` somewhere that's *not* scaled by the row stride, just the vector width or not at all.  And/or that you'd `_mm_load` from 8 columns, not `set1`.  And BTW, your change maybe makes it run faster for 48x48 by changing the ratio from 2 loads per FMA to 1 load per FMA.

Comment: I have a debug function which outputs the operands and the result into python code and checks it with np.allclose, unless I made some mistake in this debug code I think this new version is correct.

Comment: Does your test harness randomize the input elements so it's not something like all zeros or other simple pattern that could get the right answer by adding the wrong things?  If so then it's probably fine and I was just expecting your code to work differently from the way it actually does.  It's super weird to do strided loads inside the inner-most loop *and* strided stores at the end.  Why not accumulate dot-products for elements that are contiguous in the output matrix?

Comment: Yes all inputs are randomized. This code comes from many iterations over a vague idea on what could be fun to do with avx512, right now it is working on eight lines blocks (NB_L_STRIDE) of the result, 8 columns at a time (length of __mm512d). Maybe it is not the most intuitive way of doing things and most probably not the most efficient. If I can find the necessary motivation I'll rewrite it working on consecutive vectors but as a spare time project being faster than Numpy (on a very limited test case though) is already satisfying enough.

Comment: Yeah, I think I see how it's working.  It's pretty much the opposite of what I suggested, and will be total garbage for larger matrices.  But sure, for small problems using scattered reads with a broadcast memory source operand is fine, and the compiler can probably turn the `* A->nb_c` into incrementing a pointer by that much.

Comment: Definitely performances are awful when the problem scales up, it crumbles around 64*64. Could you extrapolate on why it matters though ? As far as I understand it on bigger problems the first thing to do is to decompose the input matrices into small blocks right ?

Comment: My point was that performance could degrade gradually / gracefully if you unrolled differently, with a memory access pattern with more spatio-temporal locality.  e.g. you touch the same line 8 times with a set1(), each one separately by touching most of the rest of the whole matrix.  Yes of course a high-performance matmul needs cache-blocking for max performance on large problem sizes, but you can make much better use of the bandwidth you use if you re-arrange a simple matmul to use all 8 elements of each cache line it touches in an inner loop.

Comment: Also, the addressing modes could probably be simpler that way, instead of needing to add multiples of `A->nb_c` inside the inner loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot I'll think about it and see if I can code something more efficient.